# Jboss showing this error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, websocket

How to solve the error given below in eclipse ?

ERROR:

```
[org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: You need to show the "previous errors" it mentions to get help.

Comment: 11:49:36,938 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Composite operation was rolled back

Comment: 11:49:37,010 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Composite operation was rolled back

Comment: ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Failed services" =>